# Using spark.read.from("xml").option("recursiveFileLookup", "true") for xml files in subdirectories

Tags: xml, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I would like to recursively load all files that are in xml format into my dataframe in a directory that has additional subdirectories.
With other file formats (txt, parquet,..) the code seems to work.

```
df = (
    spark.read
    .format("xml")
    .option("rowTag", "library")
    .option("wholetext", "true")
    .option("recursiveFileLookup","true")
    .option("pathGlobFilter", "*.xml")
    .load("path/to/dir")
)
```

I have tested this code with different file formats, but xml files are not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I found an answer right away, although it may not be entirely satisfactory.
Basically, I have found two possibilities:

1. Change format from "xml" to "text". 
    This allows recursive reading, but unfortunately the content of the xml file is not read in as nicely as before.

```
df = (
    spark.read
    .format("text")
    .option("rowTag", "library")
    .option("wholetext", "true")
    .option("recursiveFileLookup","true")
    .option("pathGlobFilter", "*.xml")
    .load("path/to/dir")
)
```

2. Append a glob pattern to the path at the load option.

```
df = (
    spark.read
    .format("xml")
    .option("rowTag", "library")
    .option("wholetext", "true")
    .load("path/to/dir/**/*.xml")
)
```

This makes the two options "recursiveFileLookup" and "pathGlobFilter" unnecessary. 
** in the glob pattern searches recursively through all directories and 
*.xml searches for files ending with .xml.

Comment: I tried to use the ´/**/´ glob pattern. But spark seems to implicitly cast  ´/**/´ to  ´/*/´. I.e. such a pattern matches to exactly one directory with any name, not to an arbitrary number of directories.
Use of ´.option("recursiveFileLookup", "true")´ does not fix the situation.